# Connecting over ssh from outside a network

Tags: ssh, routing, port-forwarding

If I have two machines running inside a LAN and they both share the same public IP address. Is there anyway I can allow someone outside the network (on the internet) to ssh into one machine without making them use a port number. (and port forwarding them on the router)

so login would be like,
ssh user@host1.domain.com
Or
ssh user@host2.domain.com

Thank you

Comment: Besides a [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing))?

Comment: But wouldn't that mean giving them each a public IP address?

Comment: If you do use a different port the outside people could just add that to their `.ssh/config` or analog file and not have to type it each time (they could also put their username and have a shorter alias so they could just `ssh host1` for example).